# String formula with variables in same sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm relatively new to excel formulas so I don't know the best way to approach this, or word it to find a good answer through the search.

I have the following data:

### [image]

I want to take the formula string that is contained in the E column for each row, replace variables with data that are in the same row and evaluate the expression. I have no idea if this is even possible, but I'm willing to try VB Macros or whatever is needed.

Using the above thinking:
     B8 = SUM(4 + (8 / 2))
     B9 = SUM(5 + (6 / 2))
     C8 = SUM(5 + (6 / 2))
     etc...

If this ISN'T possible, my real overarching goal here is to just have a single location for the formula. I will have much more than 3 columns of data so being able to update it in one location would be perfect for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: will it always be a sum formula?

Comment: @SiddharthRout As things stand right now, yes, it will always be a SUM.

Comment: ++ Good Question! Had me thinking for quite some time

Comment: This was a good question; well stated, thought out, and you showed what you're expecting.  Nicely done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used Defined Names and your formulas as they are actually written.

Select all rows with data starting from Column `A`
Then click on main tab Formulas\in the group Defined names click on Create from Selection

[image]

Then copy your formulas to the corresponding columns in row 8 and 9

[image]

[image]

Note that the defined names Created from selection are added at workbook level, and it may be an issue if there are other similar worksheets... This can be workout by creating the names at worksheet level, using the Define name option instead.

using the

Comment: Ahhh, clever thinking...gets rid of having to use a convoluted formula.  Also, +1 for me as I've never seen the "Create Names" popup, nice to know!

Comment: @BruceWayne, Thanks, the only possible issue I see is that the names are create at the workbook level, and it may be an issue if there are other similar worksheets...

Comment: @SiddhartRout Thanks.. Nevertheless, it can be workout by creating the names at worksheet level. Will add this to the answer now...

Comment: I was just about to post a vba resolution, but this is nice, and much easier.

Comment: @SiddharthRout This is awesome. Clean, simple, and newbie friendly. Thanks so much EEM, and everyone else who took the time to help out.

Comment: @Blankdud most welcome, you initiate all with a very creative question.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to use a more dynamic solution, using a `Vlookup` to find the values to add together.

Here's how I have the data (Note the formula shown is old, see edit):

[image]

The first two answer blocks are (respectively):

`=SUM(VLOOKUP("Az",$A$2:$D$6,column(),FALSE)+(VLOOKUP("Cx",$A$2:$D$6,column(),FALSE)/2))`
`=SUM(VLOOKUP("By",$A$2:$D$6,column(),FALSE)+(VLOOKUP("Ev",$A$2:$D$6,column(),FALSE)/VLOOKUP("Dw",$A$2:$D$6,column(),FALSE)))`

...and drag over.

But I realize you're looking, in the end, to be able to perhaps more quickly edit the formula variables, so my second two answers (rows 11 and 12) use the column F, G, and H to look for the variable:

`=SUM(VLOOKUP($F$11,$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)+(VLOOKUP($G$11,$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)/2))`
and
`=SUM(VLOOKUP($F$12,$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)+(VLOOKUP($G$12,$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)/VLOOKUP($H$12,$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)))`

Does that kind of get you where you wanted? I'm trying to think of a way using perhaps `indirect()` ro use `E8` and `E9` more directly, so if you edit that formulas, the others change too...

**Edit** - Here's the "best"  solution, insofar as all you need to do is edit the variable names in `E8` and `E9` and the formula will update itself.  (If you follow my layout above), in `B8` use
`=SUM(VLOOKUP(MID($E$8,SEARCH("(",$E$8)+1,2),$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)+(VLOOKUP(MID($E$8,SEARCH("+(",$E$8)+2,2),$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)/2))`

and in `B9`,
`=SUM(VLOOKUP(MID($E$9,SEARCH("(",$E$9)+1,2),$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)+(VLOOKUP(MID($E$9,SEARCH("+(",$E$9)+2,2),$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)/VLOOKUP(MID($E$9,SEARCH("/",$E$9)+1,2),$A$2:$D$6,COLUMN(),FALSE)))`

That way, if you want to sum, say `Sum(Cx+(Ev/2))` all you have to do is edit `E8` to that formula, and the answer1 in `B8` will update itself.

Comment: This is extremely close to what I was looking for. I was/am actually in the process of super-googling the indirect method you mentioned to use them more directly. That would be the most ideal situation for me, though this could also work.

Comment: @Blankdud - I just edited my post with a more robust formula.  It's not `Indirect()` but, as far as I can tell, it should work for you.  Note: If your variable names are more than two digits, you'll need to tweak the `Mid()` formulas to return `3` places, not `2`.